# Laravel 5 Video player

Tags: laravel, frameworks, streaming, video-streaming, video-player

I am looking for advice on how to get a single promotional video to play on my website. I am using a Laravel framework. I have looked at various tutorials on github but to no avail. Is there a simple way of obtaining this?

Comment: Is it a YouTube/Vimeo video or a video that is stored in your site?

Comment: it could be either, I have made the video myself and stored it in the resources/videos folder... but i also have it uploaded on youtube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it´s a youtube video you just have to right click on the video and select **copy embed code**, then just paste this code in your html template or blade template in case you are using laravel.

This is and example for an embed code taken from YouTube:

```
<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgIqecROs5M" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: you are my hero! worked  a treat. thank you very much :)